# Maven deploy plugin keep the file name when uploading

Tags: maven, deployment, build, bamboo

I am using maven deploy plugin to upload a file inside bamboo deployment stage. I am uploading the file without pom file. When I upload the file to Nexus, the file name is changing completely. Its appending with project name, version number and build number. I want to keep the filename as it is. Any one know how to do this?

```
 mvn deploy:deploy-file 
-Dfile=${bamboo.artifacts.path.artifactFile}
-Dpackaging=cba
-url=https://nexus.internal.organisation.com/content/repositories/snapshots/
-DrepositoryId=snapshots
-DgroupId=com.organisation.art
-DartifactId=myproject
-Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maven managed repository, such as that provided by Nexus et al, is set up in a way that is intended for `deployed` products to be returned to a maven build process that has them declared as dependencies.

It is not intended to be a generic file server.

If you have Nexus 3.0 or newer then you have access to so called "raw" repositories that you can set up any way you like.

However you would not use `mvn deploy:deploy-file` to add files to it. Instead you would follow the instructions in [Uploading Files to Hosted Raw Repositories](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/raw.html#_uploading_files_to_hosted_raw_repositories).

Comment: I've already using the `curl` command. I will paste the curl command in your answer.